# .NET project with project.json cannot be built

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have .net app, and I am trying to migrate from

`packages.config`   to   `project.json` .

Everything works fine when I build the project with Vs 2015 or manually using MsBuild from a command line. The problem starts to happen when I build it on build server with the setup:

1. .NET 4.51 app
2. MSBuild 14.0.25402.0
3. Windows Server 2012
4. Microsoft Build Tools 2013, 2015 RC installed.
5. No Visual Studio installed.
6. Nuget 3.4.3.855

When doing nuget restore project.lock.json is being created, packages are downloaded to user/.nuget/packages so it looks like it's doing the job. Then I am trying to run MSBuild, and I am getting a lot of reference errors:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When I use MSBuild from developer machine, I can build this project even if I point to build server directory so it's an obvious problem with MSBuild. I suppose that something is missing with Microsoft Build Tools, any ideas?

Edit:
it looks like msbuild adds flag /reference with all nuget paths on my developer machine and it doesn't do it on build server machine.
Example:

```
 /reference:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\log4net\1.2.10\lib\log4net.dll
```

**Developer machine building the project:**

```
Build started 27/06/2016 13:29:40.
Project "Y:\13dd0660b4e0a7a0\project.Shared.Utilities\project.Shared.Utilities.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\EPPlus\4.0.4\lib\net20\EPPlus.dll
```

**Build server msbuild building the same project**

```
D:\13dd0660b4e0a7a0\project.Shared.Utilities>"C:\Program Files (x86)"\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild project.shared.utilities.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25123.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 27/06/2016 12:35:19.
Project "D:\13dd0660b4e0a7a0\project.Shared.Utilities\project.shared.utilities.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Debug\".
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Configuration.dll"
```

This is only part of the log -> as you can see /reference is passed to the first script

Comment: Which build server are you using?

Comment: @AntonSizikov  It's Teamcity which contains two build steps:
1. Nuget restore.
2. Msbuild for solution.

It's not important in this case because I tried to do it manually from command line and still msbuild fails with the same message. So it's not teamcity related but rather nuget/msbuild issue. MsBuild doesn't know how to load nuget packages into project.

Comment: just in case, can you confirm the version of MSBuild? I see that you have MBT 2013 installed... could it be the case that you're running a wrong version of MSBuild?

Comment: and FYI `project.json` is sort of dead https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/

Comment: 1. I've updated today to Microsoft Build Tools 2015 -> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25123.0 which matches exactly my msbuild from developer machine. Msbuild version is not the case, it must be something that is installed with vs2015.
2. Yes it's sort of dead but is still better than packages.config with current csproj. They are planning to allow using project.json for nuget packages maybe with different name like nuget.json but the concept will be the same. I am using project.json only for nuget packages

Comment: ok, let's look at the build log. What's the exact MSBuild command is beeing executed?

Comment: I see that /reference doesn't show on your machine, interesting.  In my case packages are restored but msbuild doesn't use them and the difference I see is this /reference parameter which is passed when I invoke msbuild on developer machine.

Comment: @AntonSizikov please look at the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. 
Copy content from developer machine to corresponding directory on your build server machine if missing.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet
```

Not sure why this is missing after build tools 2015 installation.